# Efficient evaluation of weighted average variable in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Please, considere the dataframe df generated below:

```
import pandas as pd

def creatingDataFrame():

    raw_data = {'code': [1, 2, 3, 2 , 3, 3],                
                'var1': [10, 20, 30, 20 , 30, 30],
                'var2': [2,4,6,4,6,6],
                'price': [20, 30, 40 , 50, 10, 20],
                'sells': [3, 4 , 5, 1, 2, 3]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['code', 'var1','var2', 'price', 'sells'])
    return df


if __name__=="__main__":

    df=creatingDataFrame()

    setCode=set(df['code'])


    listDF=[]
    for code in setCode:
        dfCode=df[df['code'] == code].copy()
        print(dfCode)
        lenDfCode=len(dfCode)
        if(lenDfCode==1):
            theData={'code': [dfCode['code'].iloc[0]],                
                'var1': [dfCode['var1'].iloc[0]],
                'var2': [dfCode['var2'].iloc[0]],
                'averagePrice': [dfCode['price'].iloc[0]],
                'totalSells': [dfCode['sells'].iloc[0]]
            }
        else:
            dfCode['price*sells']=dfCode['price']*dfCode['sells']
            sumSells=np.sum(dfCode['sells'])
            sumProducts=np.sum(dfCode['price*sells'])
            dfCode['totalSells']=sumSells
            av=sumProducts/sumSells
            dfCode['averagePrice']=av
            theData={'code': [dfCode['code'].iloc[0]],                
                'var1': [dfCode['var1'].iloc[0]],
                'var2': [dfCode['var2'].iloc[0]],
                'averagePrice': [dfCode['averagePrice'].iloc[0]],
                'totalSells': [dfCode['totalSells'].iloc[0]]
            }
        dfPart=pd.DataFrame(theData, columns = ['code', 'var1','var2', 'averagePrice','totalSells'])
        listDF.append(dfPart)
    newDF = pd.concat(listDF)
    print(newDF)
```

I have this dataframe

```
   code  var1  var2  price  sells
0     1    10     2     20      3
1     2    20     4     30      4
2     3    30     6     40      5
3     2    20     4     50      1
4     3    30     6     10      2
5     3    30     6     20      3
```

I want to generate the following dataframe:

```
   code  var1  var2  averagePrice  totalSells
0     1    10     2          20.0           3
0     2    20     4          34.0           5
0     3    30     6          28.0          10
```

Note that this dataframe is created from the first by evaluating the average price and total sells for each code. Furthermore, var1 and var2 are the same for each code. The python code above does that, but I know that it is inefficient. I believe that a desired solution can be done using groupby, but I am not able to generate it.

Comment: Are you looking for `df.groupby(['code', 'var1', 'var2'], as_index=False).agg({'price' : 'mean', 'sells' : sum})`?

Comment: No, I need the weighted average!

Comment: Weighted by what?

Comment: by sells as in the code above... sumSells=np.sum(dfCode['sells'])
            sumProducts=np.sum(dfCode['price*sells'])
            av=sumProducts/sumSells

Comment: Note that price average evaluated below by @Wen is different from the one I evaluated.

Comment: Now it is! Thak you. the answer was edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is different , `apply` with  `pd.Series`

```
df.groupby(['code','var1','var2']).apply(lambda x : pd.Series({'averagePrice': sum(x['sells']*x['price'])/sum(x['sells']),'totalSells':sum(x['sells'])})).reset_index()
Out[366]: 
   code  var1  var2  averagePrice  totalSells
0     1    10     2          20.0         3.0
1     2    20     4          34.0         5.0
2     3    30     6          28.0        10.0
```